# sudo pip install django

Tags: python, django, pip

So this is my first attempt at trying to install Django, and when I ran it, it successfully installed Django-1.7.3 but I received these warnings below. I wasn't able to find any information about it online so I was hoping someone could clarify what they mean, if I need to fix them, and how I could go about doing that?

Thanks! below is the output from my terminal

```bash
macbook:~ Asif$ sudo pip install Django
```

```
Password:
The directory '/Users/Asif/Library/Logs/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the debug log has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want the -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Asif/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want the -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Asif/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want the -H flag.
Collecting Django
  Downloading Django-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB)
    100% |################################| 7.4MB 2.3MB/s 
Installing collected packages: Django

Successfully installed Django-1.7.3
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These messages are just telling you that after issuing `sudo` the current user has changed to `root` and `root` isn't the owner of those directories or one of the parent directories.

`sudo -H` sets the `$HOME` environment variable to `/root` and would probably hide these but the way you did it is perfectly fine.

I'm pretty sure these messages are nothing to be concerned about, but its always good to see that people are reading them and making sure.

Also, to verify this, you can try:

```
$ sudo env | less
```

and

```
$ sudo -H env | less
```

and pay attention to the $HOME and $USER variables

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I just wanted to make sure they weren't errors that would come back and bite me down the road.

Comment: Does it mean that I should type `sudo install pip` rather than `sudo -H install pip`?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; this has been driving me nuts. However,  the details seem to be wrong, at least on Ubuntu 16.04.  I see the same values for all variables but HOME, and HOME = /root if -H is given, and my home directory if it is not.  I think this is the reverse of what you say.