# Permissions warning with sudo pip install

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am using an ubuntu 14.04 64bit machine. The system python is 2.7.6.
This is what happens when I try to pip install anything

```
thekindlyone@deepthought:~$ sudo pip install pyopenssl
The directory '/home/thekindlyone/.cache/pip/log' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the debug log has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/thekindlyone/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/thekindlyone/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyopenssl in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

pip is at 6.1.1
How do I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Have you tried it without sudo?

Comment: I get a permission denied without sudo.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `pip install --user pyopenssl`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo pip install django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004960/sudo-pip-install-django)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to use the sudo '-H' option to set the HOME environment variable to the home directory specified by the target user's password database entry.

That way, pip will use a cache directory in your root users home.

eg.

```
$ sudo -H pip install pyopenssl
```